# Youtrack REST API "Failed to create service account from Hub, giving up" error

Tags: youtrack, jetbrains-hub

I'm trying to receive data from REST Api after Authorization in Hub. Here is my actions:

1.Authenticate application in Hub using Client credentials flow (by the way, is it right flow choice for chat bot?)

```
POST /api/rest/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: hub.example.com
Authorization: Basic base64(service_id + “:” + service_secret)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&scope=YOUTRACK_SERVICE_ID
```

2.Then i'm trying to get issues from YouTrack, using recieved access token

```
GET /rest/issue HTTP/1.1
Host: yt.example.com
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
Accept: application/json
```

Response has status 500 with this message
`{"value": "Failed to create service account from Hub, giving up"}`

Both Hub and YouTrack is stand-alone.

What's going on and what should i do? Thanks

Comment: Looks pretty similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-34304

Comment: @Jk1 this may be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating YouTrack to fresh build fixes issue.
Thanks to [Jk1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1196603/jk1)'s comment above.